# How to get data from Tally ERP Accounting System to mysql through PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in tally. I need to take the data from it and store it in MySql DB through PHP. I searched all through google, but i didn't get enough reference.

Is it possible to export data from tally to a format that can be parsed by PHP, such as XML? If so, how is it done?

NOTE: For those who dont know tally, it's an inventory management software application.

Comment: Carry the data in XML from Tally

Comment: If you have any reference let me know, because i'm not clear that how to go with it.

Comment: I've edited your question on the assumption that you _unwittingly_ edited your post to look like an advertisement for tally for clarification purposes.

Comment: @OMTheEternity I think he's stuck on precisely how to do that.

Comment: http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/1425469.htm

Comment: Yes Tim you are right. I don't know it precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Tally.ERP supports Data export in CSV and XML formats. One can easily build a CSV/XML parser in php to parse the exported data and push to a MySQL Database. However, you must design the MySQL database and tables to have all the required columns which is to be mapped by Tally ERP voucher record attributes.

Besides, Tally.ERP provides web api using which you can connect to Tally over port 9000 and communicate with its collections via XML Interface (GET/POST). I had built a connector application using the same technique to allow two way data transaction between Tally and an e-commerce website.

You can read more about the integration possibilities by following the link here [Tally ERP Integration Capabilities](http://www.tallysolutions.com/website/html/tallydeveloper/integration-capabilities.php)